# jQuery Form Clear Script Failing to Recognize Dropdowns

Tags: jquery, html, forms, select

I need to clear multiple forms on a page without restarting the page.
I am using the following script. However, you cannot reference "select" in this manner.
How would I go about resetting my single-select dropdowns?

```
$(':input','#CreditForm','#ProxyForm','#AppIDForm').each(function()
{
    switch(this.type)
    {
        case "text":
        case "textarea":
        case "hidden":
        {
           this.value = ''; break;
        }
        case "radio":
        case "checkbox":
        {
            this.checked=false; break;
        }
        case "select":
        {
            $(this).prop("selectedIndex", 0); break;
        }
        case "file":
        {
            $(this).value = ""; break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can not use reset ()?

Comment: You have to change your `case` for `select`. `this.type` returns `select-one` for single `select` and `select-multiple` if you are using multiple `select`.

Comment: Reset does not clear the form. it goes back to initial values, which is problematic in this instance..

Comment: @Atal Prateek - That's it! select-one did the trick. Post as an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your `case` for `select`. this.type returns `select-one` for single `select` and `select-multiple` if you are using multiple `select`.

```
$(':input','#CreditForm','#ProxyForm','#AppIDForm').each(function()
{
    switch(this.type)
    {
        case "text":
        case "textarea":
        case "hidden":
        {
           this.value = ''; break;
        }
        case "radio":
        case "checkbox":
        {
            this.checked=false; break;
        }
        case "select-one":
        {
            $(this).prop("selectedIndex", 0); break;
        }
        case "file":
        {
            $(this).value = ""; break;
        }
    }
});
```